# JQuery: New "Pop-up Div" on mouse hover at relative postion of "My Div"

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I want to create a "mouseover" pop-up div dynamically, just like What we get in Stackoverflow (When mouse over a tag)/Google+ (when mouseover a friend image).

Curretly I am able to get the text from AJAX, but i am unable to place that in a "Catchy cool" look & feel.

Is there any wasy way to do this in JQuery?

Comment: What have you tried? What's your mark-up? What do you consider to be 'catchy and cool'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it's not the right way to help but I wrote some code for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/w8qan/11/

It is not perfect - i recommend reading about jQuery's [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) methods and differences between them.

If you want you popups "stylish" - use CSS the way you want, use jQuery's [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), etc. I focused on displaying your description where you want it.

Comment: Przemek Thanks a lot for your help.
Thanks for introducing me to http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) method to create cool custom animations..

For more widely-used effects have a look at this list of jQuery options http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/